# How to format date using message.properties on thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and I need to format this field to a specific date. It's working the way it is, but I need the date format to be into the message.properties.
So this is working:

```
<input type="text" id="dtFrom" class="form-control " placeholder="yyyy-MMM-dd" th:attr="placeholder=''+#{default.date.format}+''" autocomplete="off" th:name="startDate" th:value="${srchCmd.startDate}?${#dates.format(srchCmd.startDate, 'yyyy-MMM-dd')}">
    </input>
```

But instead I need something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="dtFrom" class="form-control " placeholder="yyyy-MMM-dd" th:attr="placeholder=''+#{default.date.format}+''" autocomplete="off" th:name="startDate" th:value="${srchCmd.startDate}?${#dates.format(srchCmd.startDate, #{default.date.format})}">
    </input>
```

When I select the date instead of having the date formatted on the text input I have this:

```
??welco12e.12essage_en_US??
```

How is the right way to use #{} inside ${}? Not sure if that's the problem though.

Answer (score 2):

My usage is slightly different, but, I was able to get the basic concept to  work using:

```
<span th:text="${#dates.format(timestamp, #messages.msg('timestampFormat'))}">10/31/2018 11:59:07 -0500</span>
```

where my messages.properties file contains a (valid) value for 'timestampFormat', and timestamp is an available Model attribute (type Instant, for java8).

Note that I had to use #messages.msg('key') explicitly here.